# Como puedo hacer que una columna repita el mismo numero en sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Como puedo hacer que una columna repita varias veces el numero o palabra especifica y agregarla en una tabla o si se puede usar `replicate` en vez de juntar la tabla como se haría?

> Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y unirla con esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Como un CROSS JOIN? ¿Cuál es el resultado que buscas?

Comment: Lo que busco es: Hacer que en una columna agregada se le ponga ese 1 pero repetido como en el ejemplos o palabra como tom pero repetido hasta le final de la tabla.

Comment: Si mostras el query que tira la segunda tabla, la solucion es una pavada (y realmente, es una pavada, ni siquiera necesitas un join)

Comment: Y el query que intentaste?

Comment: esto: `select producto, porcentaje, 1 as Pregunta from tu_tabla` tal vez ?